# Intersection observer in Angular 7/Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, intersection-observer

I am trying to follow various tutorials on the IntersectionObserver API, such as [this one](https://alligator.io/js/intersection-observer/).

Adding the sample code into my component's TS file:

```
const myImg = document.querySelector('.animate-me');

observer = new IntersectionObserver((entry, observer) => {
  console.log('entry:', entry);
  console.log('observer:', observer);
});

observer.observe(myImg);
```

Gives me an error:

> error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'observer'.

Also, it complains about 
`const myImg = document.querySelector('.animate-me');`

> A class member cannot have the 'const' keyword.ts(1248)

what am I missing here?

Comment: rename args maybe

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the error `A class member cannot have the 'const' keyword.ts(1248)`, you are doing `const myImg = ...` inside a class.
You do not have to have const when you declare it, this should do
`myImg = document.querySelector('.animate-me');`

I think the error `error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'observer'.` is because you have a propery called `observer` and an `IntersectionObserver` parameter is also called `observer`.

The following code should work :

```js
myImg = document.querySelector('.animate-me');

observer = new IntersectionObserver((entry, obs) => {
  console.log('entry:', entry);
  console.log('observer:', obs);
});

observer.observe(myImg);
```

Comment: Are you in an Angular component?

Comment: yes.  i have tried putting this in the constructor, too.  but then I get `Failed to execute 'observe' on 'IntersectionObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'`

Comment: The code should be executed after the view is initialized, I implemented the `AfterViewInit` and put the code into the implementation.

This is a working component, could you try this:
```export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit  {
  private observer: IntersectionObserver;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const myImg = document.querySelector('.animate-me');
    console.log(myImg);
    this.observer = new IntersectionObserver((entry, observer) => {
      console.log('entry:', entry);
      console.log('observer:', observer);
    });
    this.observer.observe(myImg);
  }
}```

Comment: That seems to work, except it logs to the console on page load in addition to when the image is scrolled into view.

Comment: This is because when the page load, your element intersects out of the viewport and when you scroll down, it intersects in of the viewport.

Comment: So, how do I fire something only on entry (when the item enter the viewport)?

Comment: Looks like `console.log('intersecting: ', entry[0].isIntersecting);` works